# Razorpay Implementation in Next.js and Node.js - Handling Plan Upgrades and Refunds

Tags: node.js, next.js, razorpay

I am trying to figure out how to handle a scenario with Razorpay in Next.js and Node.js

A user subscribed our premium plan (Rs 49 + fees/taxes) on the 1st of March. But on the 20th, they've got their eyes set on the Enterprise plan (Rs 99 + the usual extras).
Now, here's where I'm scratching my head: on the 20th, I want to either:

a. Charge the user Rs 99 + extra stuff and then refund Rs 49 * 10/30.
b. Charge the user (Rs 99 + extra stuff) - (Rs 49 * 10/30).

I'm not sure if Razorpay has similar functionality, and I couldn't find much on it. Anyone out there who's have worked with Razorpay and can drop some wisdom? Maybe some online forums or documentation reference. Help is appreciated.